# How do I change the Google Maps zoom control style?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API v3.17

Here's my code:

```
    this._options = {
        zoom: this._params.zoom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(this._params.center.lat, this._params.center.lng),

        // Disabled controls
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,

        // Zoom control
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
        },

        // Disable scrollwheel and double-click zooming
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true // Because clicking through images results in a zoom
    };

    this._map = new google.maps.Map(this._el, this._options);
```

I'm getting an old-style Google Map, with little zoom icons (see image, left side).

What I'm looking for is the larger icons, per the API docs (see image, right side).

[image]

My code is identical to what they're saying to do... what am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Note that ["signed_in" maps are not available in v3.17](http://jsfiddle.net/cw34pkvy/5/), but [are available from 3.18 on](http://jsfiddle.net/cw34pkvy/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms `SMALL` and `LARGE` are misleading a bit, they are not related to the size, they mean used with a zoom-control: hide or show the slider.

There is no built-in option to set the "size".

What you see on the right side seems to be a [signed-in map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin), which uses different controls.

Note: Signed-in maps aren't available in v3.17

Comment: Thanks, I had tried using a signed-in map, thinking that was the problem, but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Signed-in maps aren't available in v3.17